# Taking multivitamin tablets without workout , will it cause any problems ?

Tags: recovery, vitamins, gym

I was doing workout last year and was regularly taking multivitamins and whey protein. But now, I am resting after a bone fracture, So I am no regular to Gym. I am not taking meat and heavy foods now so I am starting to  feel  weak. So Started taking multivitamins (Anavite from Gaspari Nutrition) again.

My doubt is taking multivitamins without a regular exercise ? Is it good or bad ? Will it speed my recovery ?

Comment: I suggest you add to your question why you suspect it might be bad

Comment: @Ivo - I fear the amount of high vitamin content may cause some disorders like (indigestion or ulcers or unknown problems) and I forgot to mention these vitamins are giving huge erections better than those old days. :(

Comment: my suggestion was to edit it into your answer not add it as a comment ;-) Either way, why do you think it's safe to take vitamins when you work out, but unsafe when you don't? Do you have any basis for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you taking a typical dose of multi vitamins? If so then keep it up. Thousands if not millions of people are taking a multi without exercising regularly. Taking a multi will help you stay healthier overall which will help you recover faster. For no other reason than your body doesn't have to work as hard to fight off illness.

I don't quite understand the train of thought between: you changed your diet, you started feeling weak, you took a multi vitamin. It seems to me that the change in diet is what's having the adverse effects on you and that is where you need to fix in order to feel less weak.

Answer (score 1):

***The Truth*** 
People tend to go overboard with the **POWER** of vitamins. You're likely getting what you need from food already, but taking a multi-vitamin won't hurt.

**Fat Soluble** 
Vitamins A, D, E, K are stored in the liver and the only vitamins you can "overdose" in a healthy adult this is faily rare.

**Why?** 
They can build up in your system as they don't dissolve in water. Again if you're healthy and aren't taking 1/2 a bottle of multi-vitamins daily this is something you really don't need to think too much about.

**Water Soluble** 
Vitamins B and C are filtered by the renal system (your kidneys).

**Misconceptions** 
Mega Does of Vitamin C (or any other water soluble) will cure your cold. The majority of research shows it does nothing.  The placebo effect is a powerful thing.

**Special Populations**
One big exception is B-12 for vegan or vegetarians patients.  Found in meat, dairy and soy it's recommended to take a B-12 supplement.

**Why?** 
  Your stomach produces a protein called gastric intrinsic factor (GIF). GIF is required by the small intestine to absorb B12.  Without this your body cannot create red blood cells.